# what is BaseDataList in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, system.web.ui.webcontrols

today I seen [BaseDataList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basedatalist.aspx) in MSDN Tutorial.But I am confuse about BaseDataLIst control / class.
Is it concept or web form control ? or Is it base class for DataControls in asp.NET
According to msdn they were showing its similar to DataList and DataGrid controls. BaseDataList description also available from .Net 2.0 to till now.
Can you please answer to understand concept.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It is not a control, it's an [abstract class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173150.aspx) meaning that it provides base functionality that must be inherited by another class to be used. In this case it provides common functionality for the DataList and DataGrid controls so that methods like [GetData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basedatalist.getdata.aspx) and events like [SelectedIndexChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basedatalist.selectedindexchanged.aspx) are available to both.